# Tomcat fails to start app and times out -- last line in log is just the word "bad"

Tags: tomcat, grails

When using grails run-war my war file builds but the server won't start.

Here is the command I am using:
    `run-war -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=512m --stacktrace`

Here is the error in the console output:

```
| Building WAR file.....
| Done creating WAR target/SommelierServerTest-0.1.war
| Running Grails application
| Error Tomcat failed to start the app in 3000 seconds (see output in /Users/rentsls57/Uptown Network/UptownServer/branches/philBranch/target/tomcat-out.txt) (N
OTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Tomcat failed to start the app in 3000 seconds (see output in /Users/rentsls57/Uptown Network/UptownServer/branches/philBranch/targe
t/tomcat-out.txt)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.IsolatedWarTomcatServer.doStart(IsolatedWarTomcatServer.groovy:127)
    at org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:102)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:176)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:153)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runWar(_GrailsRun_groovy:130)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:81)
    at RunWar$_run_closure1.doCall(RunWar.groovy:49)
| Error Server failed to start: java.lang.RuntimeException: Tomcat failed to start the app in 3000 seconds (see output in /Users/rentsls57/Uptown Network/Uptown
Server/branches/philBranch/target/tomcat-out.txt)
```

And here are some relevant lines from tomcat-out.txt log file:

```
2012-11-22 17:07:08,394 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG context.GrailsContextLoader  - [GrailsContextLoader] Loading context. Creating parent application context
2012-11-22 17:07:12,944 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG xri.LocalXriResolver  - Initializing Discovery object...
2012-11-22 17:07:13,099 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG security.Init  - SignatureAlgorithm.register(http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-ripemd160, org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.IntegrityHmac$IntegrityHmacRIPEMD160)    
2012-11-22 17:07:16,326 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG spring.BeanBuilder  - Configuring controller recommendation.RecommendationController
2012-11-22 17:07:17,243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin  - Not found: Searchable
2012-11-22 17:07:17,243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin  - Trying to load config from 'SearchableConfiguration.class'
2012-11-22 17:07:17,247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin  - Not found: SearchableConfiguration
2012-11-22 17:07:17,248 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin  - Defining Compass and Compass::GPS beans
2012-11-22 17:07:17,291 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin  - Done defining Compass and Compass::GPS beans
2012-11-22 17:07:17,341 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ShiroGrailsPlugin  - Registering realm: grails.plugins.nimble.core.OpenIDRealm
2012-11-22 17:07:17,357 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ShiroGrailsPlugin  - Registering realm: grails.plugins.nimble.core.FacebookRealm
2012-11-22 17:07:17,357 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  ShiroGrailsPlugin  - Registering realm: grails.plugins.nimble.core.LocalizedRealm
2012-11-22 17:07:17,892 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor  - postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry start
2012-11-22 17:07:17,895 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor  - updated Root bean: class [grails.plugin.cache.GrailsAnnotationCacheOperationSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null
2012-11-22 17:07:17,896 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  cache.CacheBeanPostProcessor  - postProcessBeanFactory
2012-11-22 17:07:20,841 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  util.GrailsUtil  - [WARNING] Property [first] of domain class grails.plugins.nimble.core.LevelPermission has type [java.lang.Object] and doesn't support constraint [minSize]. This constraint will not be checked during validation.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,251 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  config.ConfigurationFactory  - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/Users/rentsls57/.grails/2.1.1/projects/SommelierServerTest/war/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2012-11-22 17:07:21,251 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from URL: jar:file:/Users/rentsls57/.grails/2.1.1/projects/SommelierServerTest/war/WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-2.4.6.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
2012-11-22 17:07:21,251 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationFactory  - Configuring ehcache from InputStream
2012-11-22 17:07:21,292 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
2012-11-22 17:07:21,292 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.BeanHandler  - Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
2012-11-22 17:07:21,292 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.DiskStoreConfiguration  - Disk Store Path: /var/folders/v0/hb46n1754md6nyjh96p47tq40000gn/T/
2012-11-22 17:07:21,331 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG util.PropertyUtil  - propertiesString is null.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,333 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
2012-11-22 17:07:21,369 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
2012-11-22 17:07:21,369 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
2012-11-22 17:07:21,370 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
2012-11-22 17:07:21,586 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Permission]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,595 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Permission.data
2012-11-22 17:07:21,609 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Permission
2012-11-22 17:07:21,610 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Permission'.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,610 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Permission
2012-11-22 17:07:21,891 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,891 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.data
2012-11-22 17:07:21,900 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group
2012-11-22 17:07:21,900 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group'.
2012-11-22 17:07:21,900 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group
2012-11-22 17:07:22,053 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.ProfileBase]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,053 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.ProfileBase.data
2012-11-22 17:07:22,054 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.ProfileBase
2012-11-22 17:07:22,054 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.ProfileBase'.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,054 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.ProfileBase
2012-11-22 17:07:22,739 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,739 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.data
2012-11-22 17:07:22,750 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role
2012-11-22 17:07:22,750 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role'.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,750 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role
2012-11-22 17:07:22,920 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,920 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.data
2012-11-22 17:07:22,921 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase
2012-11-22 17:07:22,921 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase'.
2012-11-22 17:07:22,921 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase
2012-11-22 17:07:23,112 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.permissions]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,112 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.permissions.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,112 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:23,113 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.permissions'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,113 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:23,115 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.groups]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,115 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.groups.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,116 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.groups
2012-11-22 17:07:23,116 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.groups'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,116 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.groups
2012-11-22 17:07:23,117 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.permissions]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,118 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.permissions.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,118 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:23,118 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.permissions'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,118 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:23,123 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.groups]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,124 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.groups.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,124 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.groups
2012-11-22 17:07:23,124 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.groups'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,124 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.groups
2012-11-22 17:07:23,125 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.users]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,126 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.users.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,136 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.users
2012-11-22 17:07:23,136 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.users'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,136 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.users
2012-11-22 17:07:23,137 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.roles]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,137 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.roles.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,146 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.roles
2012-11-22 17:07:23,146 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.roles'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,146 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.roles
2012-11-22 17:07:23,148 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.users]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,148 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.users.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,149 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.users
2012-11-22 17:07:23,149 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.users'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,149 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Group.users
2012-11-22 17:07:23,150 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.roles]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,150 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.roles.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,156 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.roles
2012-11-22 17:07:23,156 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.roles'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,156 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.UserBase.roles
2012-11-22 17:07:23,159 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.permissions]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,160 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.permissions.data
2012-11-22 17:07:23,163 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:23,163 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.permissions'.
2012-11-22 17:07:23,163 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: grails.plugins.nimble.core.Role.permissions
2012-11-22 17:07:42,568 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:42,569 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data
2012-11-22 17:07:42,570 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
2012-11-22 17:07:42,570 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache'.
2012-11-22 17:07:42,570 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
2012-11-22 17:07:42,573 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
2012-11-22 17:07:42,573 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG factories.DiskOverflowStorageFactory  - Deleting data file org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data
2012-11-22 17:07:42,574 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG ehcache.Cache  - Initialised cache: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
2012-11-22 17:07:42,574 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG config.ConfigurationHelper  - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache'.
2012-11-22 17:07:42,574 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - started EHCache region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
2012-11-22 17:07:42,883 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin logging-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/logging-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,885 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin core-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/core-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,887 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin i18n-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/i18n-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,889 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin codecs-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/codecs-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,891 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin groovy-pages-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/groovy-pages-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,892 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin url-mappings-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/url-mappings-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,894 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin controllers-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/controllers-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,916 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin filters-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/filters-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,917 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin mime-types-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/mime-types-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,918 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin domain-class-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/domain-class-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:42,919 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin validation-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/validation-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2012-11-22 17:07:46,459 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG association.Association  - Creating association, type: HMAC-SHA256 handle:  expires: Thu Nov 22 17:07:46 EST 2012
2012-11-22 17:07:46,491 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG xri.LocalXriResolver  - Initializing Discovery object...
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG params.DefaultHttpParams  - Set parameter http.protocol.max-redirects = 0
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG params.DefaultHttpParams  - Set parameter http.protocol.allow-circular-redirects = false
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG params.DefaultHttpParams  - Set parameter http.socket.timeout = 10000
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG params.DefaultHttpParams  - Set parameter http.connection.timeout = 10000
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG params.DefaultHttpParams  - Set parameter http.protocol.cookie-policy = ignoreCookies
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG association.Association  - Generated SHA256 MAC key: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77fcef
2012-11-22 17:07:46,492 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG association.Association  - Creating association, type: HMAC-SHA256 handle:  expires: Thu Nov 22 17:07:46 EST 2012
bad
```

I don't know why the i18n resources are not there, but would that cause the server to hang?

The very last line is just "bad". What does that mean?  Certainly, not "good".

I am using Eclipse with STS 2.9.2 on a Mac, Grails 2.1.1, Java 1.6, and compiling with Groovy 1.8.

Hints:  I just upgraded from Grails 1.3.6 to 2.1.1.  The app runs fine with grails run-app.

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in my DataSource.groovy file that prevented the dataSource{} block from being read, so the url, driverClassName, etc of my database were never set.  Doh!

Problem solved.