# support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource Could not resolve any resources for plugin

Tags: tomcat, grails, plugins, deployment, war

war file deploy to tomcat fails with a bunch of messages about plugins not found, these seem to be core plugins. It's my first deploy so likely this is a pretty basic question.

Am I missing some standard dependency?

```
support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource Could not resolve any resources for plugin logging-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/logging-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource Could not resolve any resources for plugin core-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/core-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource Could not resolve any resources for plugin url-mappings-2.1.1
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/plugins/url-mappings-2.1.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

app.grails.version=2.1.1

Simple application runs fine local desktop from 
Eclipse SpringSource Tool Suite 
Version: 2.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201205071000

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "debug" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // SendGrid repo http://grails.org/plugin/sendgrid
        mavenRepo "http://repo.desirableobjects.co.uk/"

        mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots"
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        //
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        //test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-1.7"


    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        runtime ":mail:1.0.1"
        runtime ':sendgrid:0.2'

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0'
        compile ":marshallers:0.4"
        //compile ":restrpc:0.9.6"
        runtime ":webxml:1.4.1"
        compile ":rabbitmq:1.0.0"

        test ":spock:0.7" 
// add this for Grails 2.2 uses Groovy 2.0, when we upgrade
//              {
//              exclude "spock-grails-support"
//              }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get the answer from the other guy!
That's a message cause my app is in debug mode.  But doesn't stop the application, I had an error later that was in fact deadly to the application, hence the reason it wouldn't start.  

Thus his comment about fixing a db conf or something.  Same thing here, the app was dying because of something else.   Now I fixed that, and the message warnings are still there.  

:(

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat fails to start app and times out -- last line in log is just the word "bad"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521358/tomcat-fails-to-start-app-and-times-out-last-line-in-log-is-just-the-word-ba)

This question basically indicated that it was another problem. The real answer is that this was not causing the final war application startup problem, it was in his case the database config and in my case the rabbitmq config.

The verbose debug logging shows the error, the failure to startup is the fault of another error, this message can be effectively ignored.